# How to fix "Method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::links does not exist."?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

First I use `pagination` and I want to change to `all` in my Controller, but I got the error above.

This is what I tried :

```
$c = CarModel::all();
```

My code :

```
 public function index()
{
    //$c = CarModel::all(); //got error when use this
    $c = CarModel::paginate(3);

    return view('car.car',compact('c'));
}
```

I want to change to `$c = CarModel::all();` but I got error.

Comment: You must show relevant code from your controller.

Comment: public function index()
    {
        //$c = CarModel::all();
        $c = CarModel::paginate(3); 

        return view('car.car',compact('c'));
    }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like you are using ->links() method in your "car.car" view, this method is only available when you use pagination